# How to get detailed diagnostics from CRT Memory Manager in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, diagnostics, msvcrt

For the purposes of debugging and diagnosing memory fragmentation, I'd like to be able to query the memory manager (the default one provided for C++ applications) for certain information, such as the number of non-contiguous free blocks and the size of each of those.

I envision a way to essentially scan or iterate the entire heap from beginning to end and look at the details of everything. If I see a chunk of non-free memory here, how big is that in bytes? Next, I may encounter a free block, how big is that one?

I've tried swapping out our memory manager with something from a third party, but as of right now our code base is too complex, and I kept getting crashes, even though I tried various tricks. So I have to either depend on some CRT heap diagnostic functions to do this or some tool that will do it for me.

Help (and code examples in C++) is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sound of things, you're looking for [`_heapwalk`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0c183dk.aspx). The linked page includes a small demonstration.